# WD My Passport, Read Only on Gnome but not on Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, hard-drive, portable

I have a 2TB Western Digital My Passport Drive that I use quite frequently for work. It is formatted as a FAT32 Filesystem and up to this point I have had no issues.

At work I use two different computers, one is a Windows 10 machine and the other is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I still have no issues moving the drive between those two machines.

Recently I decided to give Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 a try at home, so I jumped in and made my home machine Gnome.  The Passport now shows up on the Gnome machine only as Read Only and when I try to access any Media directory, I get an error telling me that one or more of the files in the folder is corrupt and cannot open.

I have to admit I am stumped. I'm no genius, but I figure if it works fine on the other two machines, it should work fine on this one as well, Yes?

Can anyone give me a hint, please?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd connect the Passport to your Windows 10 machine at work, open an administrative command prompt window and type `chkdsk /f d:` changing the "d" to the correct drive letter, and see if that finds/fixes any problems. Lastly, I'd propose that you consider a NTFS partition, instead of FAT32.

Comment: I will give it a look, thanks.
I thought NTFS was just Windows, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: [SOLVED] After running chkdsk and allowing it to fix anything it thought was a problem, I still had the same issue.

I offloaded all the data onto my hard drive and re-partitioned and formatted the passport as NTFS. Back in business now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

I'd connect the Passport to your Windows 10 machine at work, open an administrative command prompt window and type chkdsk /f d: changing the "d" to the correct drive letter, and see if that finds/fixes any problems.

Lastly, I'd propose that you consider a NTFS partition, instead of FAT32.

**Update:**

Reinitialized the drive as NTFS and all is well.